# GetMatchingProductForIdResponse no expected

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have been trying to read a response from Amazon for some time now but seem to be getting stuck at the point where reading in the response from an xml file.

What I am trying to do is convert the response into a C# class object so that I can manipulate it how I like before passing it over to the browser to display.

I have tried many variations of the same thing to get this to work but it keeps falling over at exactly the same point each and every time.

Below is the code that I am currently testing.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(product.ToXML());

File.WriteAllText(@"D:\myFile.xml", doc.InnerXml);
var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "Product";

xRoot.IsNullable = true;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.Model.Product), xRoot);

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\myFile.xml"))
{
    //falls over here because of unexpected elements in the xml doc
    var info = (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.Model.Product)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Exception message is :

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'> was not expected.
```

Had anyone else has this issue with Amazon responses or does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you saved only the `InnerXml`? just in case you're not aware of, that will strip out the root node and may produces an invalid XML (f.e if root node has multiple child nodes).

Try to save the `OuterXml` instead :

```
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\myFile.xml", doc.OuterXml);
```

You may need to post content of `myFile.xml` if this isn't the actual problem you're facing.